# Avoiding stack overflow and increasing performance in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, tree, monads, tarjans-algorithm

aI am trying to implement some algorithm on the tree and one of the steps is to find discovery and finish time of node processing (similar to Tarjan's SSC), which is done with global state of time. I did that in Haskell using State monad consisting of list and timer. Yet on the bigger trees I get stack overflow and slow performance on this part of code, can you suggest something to improve that?

```
data DfsState = DfsState { timer :: Int
                         , treel :: [(Int, Int, Int)]
                         }

incTimer state = state { timer = timer state + 1 }
addElem node discovery finish state = state { treel=(node,discovery,finish):treel state }

dfs :: Node -> Node -> State DfsState ()
dfs node parent = do
    modify incTimer
    discovery <- gets timer
    mapM_ (flip dfs node) . filter (/= parent) $ graph M.! node
    finish <- gets timer
    modify (addElem node discovery (finish + 1))
```

Comment: What about cycles? `filter (/= parent)` is not enough to detect them.

Comment: algorithm works on the tree so parent is enough

Comment: Did you compile with -O2? This code shouldn't be particularly slow.

Comment: Have you tried making your State strict? Accumulating thunks in the State monad is a common performance problem.

Comment: Code isn't that slow but stack overflow is bigger problem, I also compiled with -O2

Comment: Indeed making State monad strict got ride of the stack overflow, only performance boost is needed, if that is possible

Comment: You should also consider making time strict (`!Int`) and using an unboxed tuple for the tree components. `data T = T !Int !Int !Int` with `-O2 -funbox-strict-fields`.

Comment: Why is data T better than tuple?

Comment: Tuples always have boxed lazy fields. Custom data can be declared strict/unboxed, as Don shows.